# IE7 and inline-block PLUS making li expand to size of children elements

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, css-float, css

I have a very nice nav menu that is working cross browser except for IE7.

I'm floating list items with inline-block which isnt supported in IE.  I have found some work arounds for this..  the only problem is that inline-block sort of shrink wrapped my list item around the contents.. whereas all these other methods for IE7 arent doing that.  I have to assign a specific width which isnt good for this site because it is not static.

```
<ul id="mini-nav">
<li class="">
  <a href="">authenticated/basic">BASIC</a>
  <div></div>
</li>
<li class="">
  <a href="">ADVANCED</a>
  <div></div></li>
<li class="">
  <a href="">BEST PRACTICES</a>
  <div></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I need my list items here to expand to fit the size of the text within the hyperlinks.  How can I accomplish this without using inline-block.

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case?

Comment: this is a rough idea of how it should function 

http://jsfiddle.net/uh7ht/

do you see how inline-block expands to fit items?  simply using display:block and floating left doesnt produce the same results

Comment: Can you explain further or show me why you need `display: inline-block`? Replacing it with `float: left; margin-right: 4px` gives the *exact* same result as your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/uh7ht/1/ (viewed in Chrome, not IE7)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uh7ht/3/

i apologize. this is more specifically what im trying to accomplish.  the floating div inside of the list items screws things up in ie7.. any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block`. Depending on your design, you may have to add `overflow: hidden` to your `<ul>` or use a common clearfix.

Comment: this works .. but doesnt take into account that i cannot define the width of the list items..  If I could define a static width this would work just fine.